# ArcGIS Raster To Multipoint Mac/OSX alternative

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, tin, simplify, point-cloud

Is there an alternative to the [ArcGIS Raster To Multipoint](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q900000067000000) tool for Macs? The VIP thinning method is particularly of use. A comparative point cloud thinning/simplification tool to this would just as useful.

The objective is digital elevation model (DEM) (heightmap) to triangulated irregular network (TIN) (mesh) conversion on OSX.

Converting the DEM to a one-to-one (pixel to point) point cloud, to a TIN, and then using a mesh decimation algorithm is not a good option because of the sheer scale of the resulting point cloud and the time it would take to process it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions (look also at [generating TIN from DEM using MacOSX/Unix tools?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33310/generating-tin-from-dem-using-macosx-unix-tools))

- [GRASS GIS (Mac)](http://grassmac.wikidot.com/) with [r.out.xyz](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass71/manuals/r.out.xyz.html) or [r.out.ascii](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.out.ascii.html) for example;
- [QGIS (Mac)](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis) with various solutions (and SAGA GIS or GRASS GIS commands in the Processing Toolbox)
- with the [GDAL](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks#gdal_complete) library;
- with Python and the [osgeo.gdal](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/2.0.0) or [rasterio](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rasterio/0.24.0) modules;
- with R
  ...

And even with lesser known GIS  as [LandSerf](http://www.landserf.org/) (`DEM to TIN` command)

Comment: Many of the suggestions here are the same as the method described in the question, where a one-to-one point cloud is created and then Delaunay triangulation applied. The advantage of the ArcGIS Raster To Multipoint tool is that it reduces the essentially 2.5D point cloud and _then_ applies triangulation. From the documentation: "VIP - Selects a percentage of points from the input raster based on their significance." [Here is an example of how it works](http://www.grasshopper3d.com/forum/topics/pointcloud-polygon-reduction). The problem is not triangulation, it is point cloud reduction.